# Как развернуть массив задом наперед?

Tags: javascript

Задание следующее:

> Поменяйте все элементы в массиве местами, то есть тот, что был 10-м, сделайте 1-м. Тот, что был 9-м, сделайте 2-м и так далее.

Делаю а ничего не получается, точнее первые пять меняет а потом нет.
Вот код:

```
var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
var arr_2 = arr;
var i = 0;
var count = arr.length;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    document.write(arr[i] + ' ');

}
count=count-1;
i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     arr[i]=arr[count];
     arr[count]=arr_2[i];
     count=count-1;

}
document.write('<br>');
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    document.write(arr[i] + ' ');

}
```

Comment: Для этого у массивов есть специальный метод, но видно вам очень лень прочитать документацию по работе с массивами.

Comment: Вы слишком все усложнили:  
Дополнительный массив не нужен, тем более, что это не копия массива, а указатель на него, то есть тот же массив.  
Цикл крутите до середины массива и меняйте значения с головы и хвоста через промежуточную переменную:  

    a=1; b=2;
    c=b
    b=a
    a=c
P.S. Тревога на учебное задание не нужна. ТС описал что он делал, и что у него не получилось.

Comment: ВОТ ВЫ ОТВЕТИЛИ НА МОЙ ВОПРОС! СПАСИБО! это не копия массива, а указатель на него. ВОТ где моя ошибка. Я просто хотел сделать сам а не с помощью функций. Так для того что бы соображалка работала. А вам спасибо! Помогли!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Я просто оставлю это сделать: http://javascript.ru/Array/reverse

Answer (score 2):

Ну как бэ, надо еще одну переменную тут

```
for (i = 0; i <=count/2; i++) {
     var t  =  arr[count-i];
     arr[count-i]=arr[i];
     arr[i] = t;
}
```

А то у вас массивы - это один и тот же объект так как через new создан.

Учите язык программирования, на котором пишите

Comment: Я продублировал массив
var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
var arr_2 = arr;
при входе в цикл arr_2[0] = 10 а до цинкла arr_2[0]=1 не могу понять почему

Comment: Я сказал, два массива - это один массив. Это ясно?

Answer (score 1):

Вот [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/h5Efh/2/)

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var temp;
for(var i=0,j=arr.length-1; i<j; i++,j--)
{
    temp = arr[j];
    arr[j] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (arr);
```

в своё время на первом курсе имел успех в силу [сложности O(n/2)](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html).

Не всегда уступает встроенному Array.reverse()

[пруф](http://jsperf.com/javascript-array-reverse-test)

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял вы на старте ) соответственно вам нужно самое просто решение без методов, вот оно :

```
for (i = arr.length-1; i>=0 ; i--) {
    document.write(arr[i] + ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуй это:

```
arr.reduce((p,c)=>{c+=p;return c;},'').split``;
```

а в чем состоят изменения-просто аналог.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не хочется пользовать sort или вторую переменную, то вот такая петрушка:

```
var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
var newArr = [], index;
for (i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
    index = arr.length - i;
    newArr[i] = arr[index];
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.write("<br />");
var arr = new Array (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,12);
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
 
 document.write("Элемент с индексом "+[i]+" равно "+arr[i]+"</br>");
}

document.write("<br />"); 

 


document.write("<br />");  
var arr = new Array (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,12);

for (var i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
    
 document.write("Элемент с индексом "+[i]+" равно "+arr[i]+"</br>"); 
}
```

Comment: Вовремя Вы ответили...

Answer (score -3):

```
function sortFunction(a, b){
  if(a < b)
     return 1;
  if(a > b)
     return -1;
  return 0
}

var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

console.log(arr.sort(sortFunction));
```

Теперь по русски. В javascript есть метод sort, в который мы передаём свою функцию сортировки. Подробнее [тут](http://javascript.ru/Array/sort)

Comment: Мне не нужна сортировка, мне нужно поменять элементы местами. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ты с помощью сортировки поменяешь местами элементы. Попробуй хоть запустить то, что тебе предлагают =)

Comment: @MrFranke, не различаете сортировку, и то что надо поменять местами элементы?

Comment: На выходе получим массив с элементами в обратном порядке. В чем же разница?

Comment: @MrFranke, представьте массив

    {10, 5, 20, 3}

переставим (вообще обычно эту задачу называют "реверс массива"), получается

    {3, 20, 5, 10}

Ну и как это сделать сортировкой?

Comment: @avp в примере предоставлен упорядоченый массив. Никаких дополнительных условий нет.

Comment: @dimka3210, может какому-нибудь адвокату такая отмазка и понравится -:), 

а вот представьте, что Вы на работу устраиваетесь...

Comment: @avp ну если бы я устраивался на работу и так лажанулся, я бы выкрутился из ситуации, поменяв функцию сортировки на такую: 

    [10, 5, 20, 3].sort(function(){return 1});

Но это, конечно же, костыль)